# How do you make construction plywood look better?

Tags: finishing, plywood

I’ve got a 4’x8’ sheet of 5/8” sheathing plywood. It’s got knots and the surface is not smooth.

But hey, I got it for a few dollars. I’ve straightened it out. I’d like to make a few boxes for friends. And even though it’s cheap rough stuff, I still want to make the plywood look good and even feel good too.

I’m not expecting a lot, but what can be done to make this stuff look and feel fine?

Comment: We *just* had a very similar Q that was closed, it's still on the front page if you need to see why. Based on that can you reframe your query so that yours won't be? Remember that ideally the body text of every Q should have only one ? in it, so if you decide you need to ask separate things about different aspects of this feel free to ask them separately. Edit: but search first in case there are previous Q&As that cover a topic; there's certainly a prior one on smoothing cheap ply.

Answer (score 0):

Not much more you can do other than treat it like any other low quality piece of wood...

- Fill voids with wood filler or epoxy.
- Sand it smooth.
- Paint.